# How to parse date string correctly

Tags: javascript, date, jsdatepick

I have datestring, image this is `2021-03-05T18:23:42`.

I need to create `new Date()` from this, BUT
`new Date('2021-03-05T18:23:42')` will return date in timezone of current user's browser.
But I need to create `new Date()` in Grinvich (basic) timezone. Exactly 18:23 (in current case), exactly by Grinvich timezone. I mean, that when user who sits somewhere in New Yourk opens my browser, she/he will see not 18:23 like it is in string, but 13:23. Because in NYC there are GTM-5. And if user will open it in Ukraine, she/he will see 20:23 because in Ukraine there are GMT+2.

How to do this?

Comment: Check out MomentJS. It will probably do what you need here.

Comment: Or there should be Z and timezone shift @end ? Thought here could be something, but it is opposite conversion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date/60881661#60881661

Comment: See [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5619588/257182).

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that there were missed `Z` letter.

**How it works?**
There are special standartized date string format, its **ISO format.
There are no timezones**. There are only one timezone and this is Z (zulu, Grinvich).

So.. in any programming language, when we tranform any date to ISO string format, then transofrmer automaticaly do next things

1. It transofrm our date to Grinwich timezone
2. Transform Grinviched date into string

And. When we call `new Date('dateString')` constructor, then it began to read date and if it (browser) doesnt know something, then it (browser) just set something by default.

In my case, I had sent to the browser string like this `"2021-03-05T18:23:42"`
Here are year, month, day, hour, minute. But there are not timezone. So when browser read this string, he set current user's timezone by default.
But. When I add 'Z' (I mean string became `"2021-03-05T18:23:42Z"`, then I said to browser: "hey, browser, here is 2021 03 05 18:23 by Grinvich". And when I ask browser

```js
const date = new Date("2021-03-05T18:23:42Z") // pay attention at Z in the end
```

, browser make 2 things

1. Read this string and create Date object knowing that this moment in life (time) is wroted by Grinvich
2. Transform this time to time in current user's timezone


   I'm happy
   Hope your are too :)

Answer (score -1):

You can call [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) on the `Date` instance and specify a `timeZone`. Don't forget to parse it with the Zulu (`Z`) timezone specifier.

**Note:** Checkout the [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List) on Wikipedia for a list of potential timezone identifiers.

```js
const
  lang = 'en-US',                     // Localization setting 
  timestamp = '2021-03-05T18:23:42Z', // Note the 'Z' at the end
  date = new Date(timestamp),
  setText = (selector, text) => document.querySelector(selector).textContent = text,
  displayDate = (date, lang, options = {}) => date.toLocaleTimeString(lang, options),
  displayLocalDate = date => displayDate(date, lang),
  displayDateGMT = date => displayDate(date, lang, { timeZone:'GMT' }),
  displayDateUkraine = date => displayDate(date, lang, { timeZone:'Europe/Kiev' });

setText('#localDate', displayLocalDate(date));
setText('#date', displayDateGMT(date));
setText('#date-ukraine', displayDateUkraine(date));
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
  width: 14em;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

label:after {
  content: ':';
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <label>Local  </label> <span id="localDate"></span>
  <label>GMT    </label> <span id="date"></span>
  <label>Ukraine</label> <span id="date-ukraine"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but solution were much simplier :)